# No referenced table error ,while creating my db

Tags: python, mysql, flask-sqlalchemy

I open my terminal to construct my data base with SQLAlchemy , in python
The error is in the following code:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
#import SQLALchemy
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
#set the SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI key
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']= 'sqlite:///song_library.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'you-will-never-guess'
#create an SQLAlchemy object named `db` and bind it to your app
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

```py
class Item(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  playlist_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Playlist.id'))
  song_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Song.id'))

#create the Playlist model here + add a nice representation method
class Playlist(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  items = db.relationship('Item', backref='playlist', lazy='dynamic')
```

so after :

```
> python3
> from app import db
> from models import *
> db.create_all()
```

the following error raise:

> sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'user.playlist_id' could not find table 'Playlist' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'

what should I do to solve it?

Comment: You aren't showing what `db` is.

Comment: I add the declaration of db